# Increase number of Tables in Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, dedicated-server

I have one dedicated server and installed cent os 6. Also installed kloxo panel. Now I have one mysql database hosted over this server. The problem is that one database have maximum of 250 tables, but I want to increase it to 500. If try it changing in phpmyadmin it shows, you can add maximum of 250 tables in one database, but is there a way to change this limit from anywhere. Please help me.

Comment: mysql does not have any limits on no of tables & databases. Did you installed the mysql server separately or it comes with kloxo panel? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html

Comment: it comes with kloxo. please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had tried so many methods and finally got the answer. It can be done using config.inc.php file which is located inside phymyadmin folder of dedicated server, where we can insert below line:

```
$cfg['MaxTableList'] = 250;
```

Here you can set the maximum number of table you want inside one db. in abobe code this set to 250.